# What file system should I choose when formatting a flash drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows, filesystem

I need to write a few large files (larger than 4 GB) on a flash drive, but I can't do it, because the file system of the flash drive is MS-DOS (FAT32).

How should I format the flash drive, so I can write down large files into it, and then open it on a PC on windows and download these files?
What file system should I choose when formatting the flash drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) is the only format which will work for you as it will allow files greater than 4GB and work on Windows. Disk Utility can format using exFAT.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, then mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 1):

What is the capacity of your flash drive ?

More than 8GB ? If yes then NTFS will do.

If you want to use your flash drive on Windows, only FAT32 or NTFS will be nice.

If you haven't download yet, there is a lot of software that allow OS X to write into NTFS partitions. Like TUXERA NTFS or Paragon NTFS.

Comment: Why not just use exFAT?

Comment: NTFS will **not** do as it is  not writable without 3rd party software. FAT32 also has limitations. IconDaemon is correct exFAT is the way to go

Comment: Thank you for help! What is the difference between NTFS and exFAT (what limitations there are in the case of each of these file systems?)

Comment: I'll keep in mind that NTFS is also an option, thank you!